# How to create animation to make it seem like the user is walking through the home?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, animation

How to create animation to make it seem like the user is walking through the home, as it does in this app

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/3d-houses-free/id588335520?mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/temple-run/id420009108?mt=8

What will be the best approach to implement this in iOS??

Any suggestion??

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The examples you sent are not made with native iOS frameworks. I'm not sure about Temple Run but the first one is made with Unity 3D Game Engine, I'm sure about it. Because I worked with Unity and those controllers, buttons are from Unity.

Unity 3D is a very very good and popular game engine. You can have a look http://unity3d.com/

There are very good video tutorials about it too. It's not very hard to learn but you need to know basic javascript or c# and you must be good at physics.

Let me do a favor, these are nice tutorials that I worked with. You can work with them :]

TornadoTwins: https://www.youtube.com/user/TornadoTwins/videos

Jesse Etzler is very good too: https://www.youtube.com/user/JesseEtzler0

Unity3D Student: http://www.unity3dstudent.com/category/modules/

And my favourite for beginners, Walker Boys (try their free unity course)

http://walkerboystudio.com/index.html

You can search more, there are plenty. Good luck!